# Set New opened workbook as wb give Application /object-defined error

Tags: vba, excel

The whole code works well until I set new opened workbook as wb and refer it to respected range. So suppose there is nothing wrong with my If and EndIf position.I tried several times with different way. With wb , ... Object-defined error. I remove .Value from Score, it gives error. using long range statement instead of Score, also give error. Where should I change? Thank you

```
Option Explicit
Sub TryFloo()
Dim year As String, x As String, startdate As String, month As String
Dim first As Integer, second As Integer, addDay As Integer, daterow As Integer
Dim mainbk As Workbook, wb As Workbook
Dim r&, i&, m As Integer
Dim path As String
Dim Score As Range

Set mainbk = Workbooks("kumpul mean.xlsm")
r = 5
With mainbk
  If IsError(.Sheets(2).Range("E" & r)) Then    '<---- Open first If()
     Exit For
  Else
     year = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A" & r).Value
     x = Range("C" & r).Value
     addDay = Range("E" & r).Value - 1
     first = InStr(x, "/")
     second = InStr(first + 1, x, "/")
     startdate = Mid(x, 1, 2)
     month = Mid(x, first + 1, second - first - 1)

     If month = 11 Then m = 1
     If month = 12 Then m = 31
     If month = 1 Then m = 62
     End If

     path = "E:\SouthNorth\1979.xls"
     Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=path)
     wb.Activate
     daterow = m + startdate

     For i = daterow To daterow + addDay
       With wb
         Score = .Sheets(1).Range(Cells(i, 24))'<--- Application/object-defined error
         If Score.Value > 12 And Score.Value < 14 Then Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & i).Value = 1
         ElseIf Score.Value > 14 And Score.Value < 16 Then Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & i).Value = 2
         ElseIf Score.Value > 16 Then Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & i).Value = 3
         End If
       End With
      Next i
      'wb.Close SaveChanges:=True '<- left open for checking
    End If                                 '<---- close first If()
  End With
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

`wb.Range(Cells(i, 24))` is incorrect. The `Cells` is a property of a worksheet and not workbook.

Try something like this

```
wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("X" & i)
```

or

```
wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i,24)
```

Comment: Thank you @Siddharth Rout, that's works well. Sorry that I give difference question ,I edit my question above. What if i want to use With wb